# How to use python to select two bezier points and subdivide the curve between them

Tags: python, bezier-curves

I want to subdivide the curve between two control points of a bezier curve using a python script. It's very easy if I do i manually. Just enter the edit mode and select two point, then click the right mouse ,choose subdivide.  Show in Image 1,2,3.
[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

However, this seems so hard by using a python script. I use the code below, but it doesn't work.

```
    bezier_curve =  bpy.context.active_object
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT', toggle=False) 
    points = bezier_curve.data.splines[0].bezier_points
    points[1].select_control_point = True
    points[2].select_control_point = True
    bpy.ops.curve.subdivide()
```

The code above just subdivide the whole curve like Image 4 show.Anyone know how to get the effect I expected? Thank you.
[image: Image 4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine as long as not all points are selected before execution.

To avoid this add
`bpy.ops.curve.select_all(action='DESELECT')`
before selecting your active controlpoints.

```
bezier_curve =  bpy.context.active_object
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT', toggle=False) 
points = bezier_curve.data.splines[0].bezier_points

bpy.ops.curve.select_all(action='DESELECT') # new

points[1].select_control_point = True
points[2].select_control_point = True
bpy.ops.curve.subdivide()
```

Comment: Thank you! It works very well

Comment: array points start with index 0,
so points[0]..= True and pointſs[1]..=True
works better in a general case.